# Sum DF columns stored in dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe, dictionary

I got a dictionary with 3 Dataframes {0: DataFrame, 1: DataFrame, 2: DataFrame}.
Each DataFrame has the same size. 6 variables, 25 rows.
I'd like to sum all the values/rows from each DataFrame column 'Income' and pass the sum to a list.
Looking like this

```
list_of_sums = [Sum of income DF0, Sum of income DF1, Sum of income DF2]
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding a sample of your input and the expected output. We're not supposed to guess it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
list_of_sums = []
input_dict = {0: DataFrame, 1: DataFrame, 2: DataFrame}
for obj in input_dict:
    list_of_sums.append(input_dict[obj]['Income'].sum())   # use sum function and append the result to the output list.
print(list_of_sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimized one but this works.

```
import pandas as pd
d, dd, ddd = pd.DataFrame(),pd.DataFrame(),pd.DataFrame()
d['Income'] = [3,4,5,6] 
dd['Income'] = [30,40,50,60]
ddd['Income'] = [300,400,500,600]

dicts = [d,dd,ddd]
for dc in dicts:
    print(sum([s for s in dc['Income']]))
```